# Accessing all elements in an iterated list under a loop in Python

Tags: python, list, drawing, pygame, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python & Pygame: Updating all elements in a list under a loop during iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172711/python-pygame-updating-all-elements-in-a-list-under-a-loop-during-iteration)

i am working on a program in Python and using Pygame.
this is what the basic code looks like:

```
import pygame ---and other stuff necessary

Class_name():

        draw_circle()

        --some other functions--- 

i = 0 

clicks = 0

object_list = []

while 1:

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_c:
            circle_create = True
            circle_list.append(Circle())

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and circle_create == True:
            if clicks == 0:
                circle_list[i].center()
            clicks += 1


        if event.type == MOUSEMOTION and clicks == 1 and circle_create == True:
            circle_list[i].stretch()



    #circle.circle_computation()
    if circle_create == True:
        circle_list[i].draw_circle()

    if clicks == 2:
        clicks = 0
        i += 1
        circle_create = False

    pygame.display.update()
```

So basically, an object is created from the class when the key 'c' is pressed.
this object is added to a list and the list is iterated. 
the user then presses the mouse and stuff to draw a circle and create as many circles as they want.

what i want to do is have the object's function of draw_circle() to be constantly updated by the loop so that the drawn circle is shown for all objects in the list, but since the list is iterated it updates the new object added and the objects already appended are not updated.

The program, works, it draws the circles upon user input but the update problem is the only issue i need to solve.
Is there any possible way to have all elements in the list of objects being updated by the while loop? i have tried for many days and i have not been able to find a good solution. any ideas are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are not iterating over any lists right now. And `i` is always 0

Comment: 'i' is incremented by 1 when 'clicks == 2'.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in this code that you increment i

Comment: Are you trying to call the center() method on every item in the circle_list?

Comment: center() is called for the current item in the list. lets say i = 2, the third element in the list will have have center() called for that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your existing code and your stated desire to draw all of the circles and not just the most recent one I think the following code change should give you the behavior you are looking for:

```
#circle.circle_computation()
if circle_create == True:
    #circle_list[i].draw_circle()
    for j in xrange(i):
        circle_list[j].draw_circle()
```